# Couchbase Java SDK: N1QL queries that include document id

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I'm looking to perform a query on my Couchbase database using the Java client SDK, which will return a list of results that include the document id for each result.  Currently I'm using:

```
Statement stat = select("*").from(i("myBucket"))
                 .where(x(fieldIwantToGet).eq(s(valueIwantToGet)));

N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(stat);
```

However, N1qlQueryResult seems to only return a list of JsonObjects without any of the associated meta data.  Looking at the documentation it seems like I want a method that returns a list of Document objects, but I can't see any bucket methods that I call that do the job.

Anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the below query to get Document Id:

`Statement stat = select("meta(myBucket).id").from(i("myBucket"))
                 .where(x(fieldIwantToGet).eq(s(valueIwantToGet)));`

The above would return you an array of Document Id.